# Is it possible to programatically set an Eclipse RCP button as 'checked'?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I want to programatically set an Eclipse plugin action (button) such as this here:

[image]

For example, if the user presses it, I do not want it to toggle off under certain conditions.

This code here creates the action (button):

```
class MyAction extends Action {
    public MyAction() {
        super(NAME, IAction.AS_CHECK_BOX);
    }

    ...
    Thread.sleep(100); wait a little bit incase there is a thread update issue
    if (condition)
        setChecked(true); // does not work, it does not force the button to appear as depressed. It just keeps toggling.
    ...
}
```

For some reason setChecked(true) does not work.

Comment: In general, setChecked should do it.  Does that chunk of code get executed when you receive a propertyChanged for this Action?

Comment: @sharakan: yes, I see the sysout statement. I also pressed it a few times incase I was mistaken about which was on/off. I'll check it again.

Comment: Actually, what I was really asking was where that condition check code lives.  Inside `Action.run()`?  `IPropertyChangeListener.propertyChange()`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here I believe is the fact you're calling `setChecked` inside of `Action.run()`.  Since one of the effects of clicking a checkbox is to check it, you're sneakily trying to cancel the action while it's going on.  In fact, I bet the framework code sets checked to true after `Action.run()` returns, so it's stomping on your change.

`Action` has a way of letting you control this in a more defined way.  Rather than implementing `.run()`, implement [`.runWithEvent(Event)`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/Action.html#runWithEvent%28org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event%29).  This function passes in an Event object that you can use to have finer grained control.

In this case, I think you want to set [`Event.doit`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event.html#doit) to false.  From the docs:

> Setting this field to false will cancel the operation.

***Another option***

Depending on how your condition is calculated, you may want to preemptively enable/disable your checkbox when it changes.  This way you can also prevent a tooltip or similar to explain why it's disabled.